# Python: Passing parguments to file (python file1 -c file2 argfile2)

Tags: python

I have a problem to pass my arguments to a python file that is used by -c (program passed in as string).

The call in cmd looks like:

```
python file1 -c file2 argFile2
```

Normal arguments passing as below is of cource working:

```
python file1 argFile1
```

The error message I get from the first call (arguments to file2) is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1", line 224, in <module>
    raise Exception("'%s' is not a valid file or directory" % test_path)
Exception: 'argFile2' is not a valid file or directory
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Thus, my call tries to pass the argument to file1 but I want to pass them to file2. How do I do that?

Comment: Python only allows you to give it one script to run on the command line. There's no way to pass a script like your `file1` argument and also pass the `-c` argument and expect it to run as well. Instead, all the arguments after the script name will be collected into `sys.argv` where your script's code can get at them (and do anything with them it would like). You haven't shown us any of your code, so we can't help you with any issues it may have.

Comment: I don't get it. What did you expect `python file1 -c file2 argFile2` to do? You can't pass a file name to the `-c` switch...

Comment: When I do "python file1 -c file2" I run file2 as a command but in some how with connection to file1 (?). If I only run "python file2" I will get errors on import-lines that does not work, which is declared in file2.